# Filter and deactivate links and text in the force-layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nodes, simulation, force-layout

I use the force-layout in D3.js. 
Now i am able to deactivate some nodes from any movement by use a filter. In my case, the nodes i filter out are blue ones in the `else` part of the loop.
Now, when click the "button", all red nodes increase the size of the forceCollide value.

With the help of the loop in the `if` part you can see below, it is possible to make all nodes moving around normally if `firstTime` is "true" . 
    Now, my problem is, that i haven't find out, how to deactivate the links and texts that are connected to the filtered blue nodes? That means, that i wish the texts of the filtered nodes also gets filtered and get deactivated, and the links too. So, how can i get a connection to the links and texts from my filtered by attribute nodes?
    Thanks guys!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  .links line {
    stroke: #999;
    stroke-opacity: 0.6;
  }

  .nodes circle {
    stroke: #fff;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
  }
</style>
<div class="centre jumbotron">

</div>
<svg width="960" height="600"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<button>Click me</button>
<script>
  var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

  var g = svg.append("g");
  var firstTime = true;

 var colours = ["blue", "red", "green", "yellow"];

  var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) {
      return d.id;
    }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
    .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(function(d) {
        return d.r + 1;
    }));

  d3.json("https://jsonblob.com/api/6e520635-d35c-11e6-b16a-6b255c15b1a3", function(error, graph) {
    if (error) throw error;

    var link = g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "links")
      .selectAll("line")
      .data(graph.links)
      .enter().append("line")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1);

    var node = g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "nodes")
      .selectAll("circle")
      .data(graph.nodes)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .attr("fill", (d, i) => colours[i % 2])
      .call(d3.drag()
        .on("start", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("end", dragended));

    var text = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "labels")
    .selectAll("text")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("text")
    .attr("dx", 12)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .style("fill", (d, i) => colours[i % 2])
    .text(function(d) { return d.group });

    d3.select("button").on("click", function(d) {
    firstTime = false;
    node.filter(function() {
    return d3.select(this).attr("fill") === "red"
    }).each(d => d.r = 60);
    simulation.nodes(graph.nodes);
    simulation.alpha(0.8).restart();
    })


    simulation
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .on("tick", ticked);

    simulation.force("link")
      .links(graph.links);

    function ticked() {
      link
        .attr("x1", function(d) {return d.source.x;})
        .attr("y1", function(d) {return d.source.y;})
        .attr("x2", function(d) {return d.target.x;})
        .attr("y2", function(d) {return d.target.y;});


        if (firstTime) {
        node.attr("cx", d => d.x).attr("cy", d => d.y);
        } else { 

        node.filter(function(e) {
        return d3.select(this).attr("fill") != "blue"
        }).attr("cx", d => d.x).attr("cy", d => d.y);
        } 

      text
        .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; }) 
        .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; });
    }
  });

  function dragstarted(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
  }

  function dragged(d) {
    d.fx = d3.event.x;
    d.fy = d3.event.y;
  }

  function dragended(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
    d.fx = null;
    d.fy = null;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: some html would help..

Comment: Not only HTML: please create a [MCVE], so we can suggest a working answer.

Comment: I just edited it. Hope this time is is more understandable.

Comment: Not really. Please read the link I provided in the comment above. We need a running code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote the answer for your last question proposing that filter in the `tick` function because I had no idea that you had links and texts as well. Now you have a different question, and you cannot simply adapt the answer to that other question to this present question: they are different problems.

For this one, the simple solution is setting the `fx` and `fy` properties. According to the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-force):

> To fix a node in a given position, you may specify two additional properties:
>
> - fx - the node’s fixed x-position
> - fy - the node’s fixed y-position
>
> At the end of each tick, after the application of any forces, a node with a defined node.fx has node.x reset to this value and node.vx set to zero; likewise, a node with a defined node.fy has node.y reset to this value and node.vy set to zero. To unfix a node that was previously fixed, set node.fx and node.fy to null, or delete these properties.

Thus, you can do something like this inside the "click" function:

```
d3.select("button").on("click", function(d) {

    //this will fix the blue nodes
    node.filter(function() {
        return d3.select(this).attr("fill") === "blue"
    }).each(function(d) {
        d.fx = d.x;
        d.fy = d.y;
    })

    node.filter(function() {
        return d3.select(this).attr("fill") === "red"
    }).each(function(d) {
        return d.r = 80
    });

    simulation.nodes(nodes);
    simulation.alpha(0.8).restart();
})
```

Here is a demo. If you click the button, the red circles will push away the other nodes/texts, but the blue ones remain in the position. The texts and links keep connected. Dragging any of them will *release* it.

```js
var width = 400;
var height = 300;

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var nodes = [{
  name: "foo",
  color: "blue"
}, {
  name: "bar",
  color: "green"
}, {
  name: "baz",
  color: "red"
}, {
  name: "foofoo",
  color: "yellow"
}, {
  name: "foobar",
  color: "blue"
}, {
  name: "foobaz",
  color: "green"
}, {
  name: "barfoo",
  color: "red"
}, {
  name: "barbar",
  color: "yellow"
}, {
  name: "barbaz",
  color: "blue"
}];

var links = [{
  "source": 0,
  "target": 1
}, {
  "source": 0,
  "target": 2
}, {
  "source": 0,
  "target": 3
}, {
  "source": 1,
  "target": 3
}, {
  "source": 1,
  "target": 4
}, {
  "source": 2,
  "target": 5
}, {
  "source": 3,
  "target": 6
}, {
  "source": 1,
  "target": 7
}, {
  "source": 6,
  "target": 8
}, {
  "source": 0,
  "target": 7
}, {
  "source": 2,
  "target": 6
}, {
  "source": 3,
  "target": 8
}];

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force("link", d3.forceLink())
  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-50))
  .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
  .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(function(d) {
    return d.r + 1;
  }));

var link = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(links)
  .enter()
  .append("line")
  .style("stroke", "#ccc")
  .style("stroke-width", 1);

var node = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", function(d) {
    return d.r = 10;
  })
  .attr("stroke", "gray")
  .attr("stroke-width", "2px")
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    return d.color
  })
  .call(d3.drag()
    .on("start", dragstarted)
    .on("drag", dragged)
    .on("end", dragended));;

var text = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .attr("pointer-events", "none")
  .style("fill", "black")
  .attr("dy", "-1em")
  .attr("dx", "-1em")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.name;
  });

simulation.nodes(nodes);
simulation.force("link")
  .links(links);

simulation.on("tick", function() {

  link.attr("x1", function(d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
      return d.source.y;
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
      return d.target.x;
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return d.target.y;
    })

  node.attr("cx", function(d) {
    return d.x
  }).attr("cy", function(d) {
    return d.y
  });

  text.attr("x", function(d) {
    return d.x
  }).attr("y", function(d) {
    return d.y
  });

});

function dragstarted(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;
}

function dragged(d) {
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function dragended(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}

d3.select("button").on("click", function(d) {
  node.filter(function() {
    return d3.select(this).attr("fill") === "blue"
  }).each(function(d) {
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
  })
  node.filter(function() {
    return d3.select(this).attr("fill") === "red"
  }).each(function(d) {
    return d.r = 80
  });
  simulation.nodes(nodes);
  simulation.alpha(0.8).restart();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<button>Click me</button>
<br>
```

Comment: I will check your answer now. Also i just edited one more time and posted the code.